# jQuery animation not working on second time

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have an area of content that I want to animate, however the animation only works the first time that I click on the trigger. On the second click of the trigger, the animation reverses. Here is my code.

The HTML

```
<div class="drawer-content" id="signin">   
</div><!--End #signin-->
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //We hide the panel
    $('.drawer-content').css('marginTop', '-140px' );

    //When the anchor is clicked the panel will slide up        
    $('.open-drawer').click(function(){ 
        $('.drawer-content').animate({marginTop: '0px',}, 1000 );

        //Append active class to anchor
        $(this).removeClass('open-drawer').addClass('active');

        //On click the active link will cause the panel to slide down
        $('.active').click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('open-drawer');
            $('.drawer-content').animate({marginTop: '-140px',}, 1000 );
        });

    });

});//End DOM Load
```

**Edit**
Here is a live example for those who asked. Thanks!
http://livecoding.io/3854307

The comments should make this pretty self-explanatory. It works the first time, but if I try to run the animation again, the box just slides down and then slides right back up again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a live example with livecoding.io or jsfiddle so we can better help you.

Comment: Agree with previous commenter, also would like to point out that using 2 clases for when it's active and open it's just rendundant the way you use them. Also need more info about the structure of your code (including HTML) to help that's why @GabrielFlorit asked for a jsfiddle

Comment: can u share the html code to get better understanding?

Comment: Here you go. http://livecoding.io/3854307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will .slideToggle work for you? Description: Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

UPDATE!

try replacing your jquery code with this.

```
 //We hide the panel
$('.drawer-content').hide();

//When the anchor is clicked the panel will slide up        
$('.open-drawer').click(function(){
    $('.drawer-content').slideToggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your html, but what I expect is that the "click" is registered on .open-drawer, this starts the animation and sets the click handler on .active.

Now if .active is a parent (in HTML) of .open-drawer, it will notice the same click (since it't bubbling upward in the DOM), and thereby appending the animate up to the current animation.

My first suggestion would be to add an `event.stopPropagation()` in the first event handler, and see what happens.

But as mentioned, without the HTML or an example page, it's hard to spot the problem and debug.

(also see http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ )